# How can I upgrade to Worklight Fixpack 6.1.0.1 using a silent install?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, upgrade, silent-installer

I'm attempting to plan an update of a Worklight Server from 6.1.0.0 to 6.1.0.1 (Fixpack 1) using [IBM Installation Manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142). [The instructions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27028172#install-archive) only seem to cover interactive installations through the Installation Manager GUI, but I will need to do this silently/from the command-line as these are headless servers. It seems that the [`imcl`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r4/topic/com.ibm.cic.commandline.doc/topics/r_tools_imcl.html) command from Installation Manager is what I need, but it's not entirely clear how to use it with the downloaded fixpack archive: `imcl installAll` doesn't seem to have a place to specify the fixpack archive. To complicate matters, these machines have no direct internet access, so I have to update from a local archive.

Answer (score 2):

To run installation manager with imcl, follow the instructions here: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_silent_installation.html

However, to update a server in production, there are other steps to take -- before running IM and after. See here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr6101_fix_pack.html

Comment: Hello, thanks. However, the link you linked to talks only about installing using Installation Manager, not updating. It doesn't look like there are any sample response files either. Are there any working examples of how to combine the two?

Comment: The sample files listed in the doc (direct link to the files http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/Silent_Install_Sample_Files.zip ) contain a file upgrade-initially-v6.xml -- although this is not visible in the table of the doc reference I gave you. Actually, a better link would have been http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_prep_become_familiar_with_IBM_IM.html